# Transplanting young oak trees into buckets

Tags: trees

I have about 100 oak trees. I took the 100 oak trees out the ground and planted them into 5 gallon buckets. The trees were very healthy when i took them out the ground and about 3ft tall.  I used a soil sand mix i bought at a local nursery to use to replant them in the 5 gallon bucket. After about a week the trees in the 5 gallon bucket looked as they were dying.  I used a root simulator about 2 weeks in. So its now been about 2 months and the trees look almost dead. I notice at the base a sprout is coming up. What should I do altogether?

Comment: Could you tell us where in the world you are? Were the trees in leaf when you lifted them? What sort of oak tree are they (especially whether they are evergreen or deciduous)? Normally, deciduous trees are lifted when dormant in the winter. It is very hard to keep them alive if you lift them in summer.

Comment: Plus, could you tell us your ultimate goal for putting the trees into 5 gallon buckets?  What sort of light conditions are you storing them in?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you please post a picture or two? One of the trees and one including that sprout at the base would help us a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Oaks also put down quite a taproot.  If you don't either dig deep or cut it cleanly you're likely to damage the roots quite badly.  Commercial growers selling bare-roted oaks cut the taproot below ground even for smaller tress than you have.What did you do?

Answer (score 2):

Oaks are difficult to dig and replant ; I have had some luck with seedlings smaller than 12 inches. You could collect a bunch of acorns and put them in your buckets ( worms inside the acorns will destroy most of them - so bury a bunch.)